# Find max value of a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data

```
[list([29]) nan list([40])]
```

Type is pandas series

```
print(type([list([29]) nan list([40])]))

#type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>)
```

Now I need to get the max value, obviously 40, so I tried

```
hi = [list([29]) nan list([40])]
hi = hi.nlargest(1)
print(hi)
// should be
40
```

But returns error

```
  raise TypeError(f"Cannot use method '{method}' with dtype {dtype}")
  TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The provided code is not valid python, please correct

Comment: Isn't pandas a python library?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your code is not valid python. If you copy paste it in a python shell this will trigger errors

Comment: ok.    thanks .but thats the actual data printed from a function return data

Comment: That's the thing, you should provide code to reproduce the input, not a representation of the output ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
# flatten the series with explode and find max
pd.Series([list([29]), np.nan, list([40])]).explode().max()
# 40
```